# Docker for mac aborts looking for a specific character

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I'm running docker for mac with the following version

[image]

Docker has recently started failing with the following error message

```
invalid character 's' looking for beginning of value
```

I was also recently shown this dialog when trying to shut down docker after receiving the above error message:

[image]

I've tried reducing the size of the disk to fully wipe it through the preferences dialog, but that didn't eliminate the issue:

[image]

What does this error message mean and how can I resolve it?

Comment: To the close voter, Docker is most definitely in the category of "software tools primarily used by programmers", and is therefore on-topic in this regard.

Comment: One user says that the "Restore to Factory Defaults" option fixed the problem for them: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5139#issuecomment-844762740

Comment: I tried resetting to factory defaults as well, no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was because I upgraded to the latest version of Docker for Mac. I downgraded to 4.12.0 and haven't seen the problem since.